# Rails 4 google map api in bootstrap popup where google.maps.Marker is not loading on popup

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In rails 4 application I am using google map API to load the map. 
Following is my js.erb code for loading the map on bootstrap popup.

```
$('.search_map_modal').empty().append("<%=j render 'business_map', business: business_map %>");
$('#modal_<%= business_map.id %>').empty().append("<%=j render 'business_map', business: business_map %>");
$('.modal_<%= business_map.id %>').modal();
// setTimeout(function(){
// $('.modal-backdrop').removeClass('modal-backdrop')
initShowMap();
function initShowMap(){
  lat = "<%= business_map.latitude? ? business_map.latitude : '' %>"
  lngit = "<%= business_map.longitude? ? business_map.longitude : '' %>"
  if (lat == "" && lngit == ""){
    lat = '23.0225'
    lngit = '72.5714'
  }
  var myOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lngit),
    zoom: 15
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map($('#business_map'), myOptions);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    draggable:false,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lngit),
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
  });
}
```

Following is my partial business_map

```
<div class="modal fade modal_<%= business.id %> padding-top-60 map_modal" role="dialog">
  <div class="vertical-alignment-helper">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg vertical-align-center">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title"><%= business.try(:name) %></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <%= "#{business.city.try(:name)}, #{business.state.try(:name)}, #{business.try(:zipcode).try(:code)}" %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag 'business_latitude', business.latitude %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag 'business_longitude', business.longitude %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag 'business_google_location', business.google_location%>
          <%= hidden_field_tag 'radius','',:class=>"form-control radius_val",:id => "business_radius" %>
          <div id="business_map"></div>
          <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCYVXvVsVO_zdrScObnfrUH1Cu-HLx8BEA&libraries=places&callback=initShowMap"
            async defer></script>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
            Close
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

But when I open the popup firs time after reloading the screen google.maps.Map is loading but google.maps.Marker is not loading in side the popup. It's only gray box no map in it, you can see it in below image

When i click f12 then map is loading inside the popup

[image]

Comment: To troubleshoot this, it would be helpful to debug the JavaScript independent of the RoR code.  Can you share a sample of the HTML / JS generated which reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when map is used inside some element controlled using jQuery (modals, accordion etc.). Try inserting `google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");` inside `$(document).ready()` or preferably iside the function run when the modal is loaded.
Edit: I think it might look like so:
`$( "#modal_<%= business_map.id %>" ).on("shown.bs.modal", function(){ google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");});`